# ¿no me busca segun la expresion regular generada por mi?

Tags: python, bucle-for

Me conecto por FTP a servidor y hago un listado de lo que hay, y despúes creo un patron para buscar algún fichero con una condición (*.bak),

```
 if puerto=='21':     
        print('---->Entramos por el puerto 21')   

        # Hacemos la conexión Ftp a servidor
        ftp = FTP(servidor)

        # Hacemos el login de usuario y passwd, 
        ftp.login(user=usuario, passwd=contrasena)

        # La función FTP.cwd() es utilizada para cambiar de directorio o carpeta remota
        ftp.cwd(rutaServer)

        # Listamos y lo guardamos en la variable listadoFich
        listadoFich=ftp.retrlines('LIST')

        print(listadoFich)

        # Generamos un bucle para recorrer listadoFich e intentamos y buscar por patrón e imprimir por pantalla.
No necesariamente el archivo tiene .patron , el nombre del archivo puede tener patron a la mitad de su nombre como sale en la foto mas abajo
        for fichero in listadoFich:

            print('patron -----> '+ patron )

            if fichero.endswith(patron):
                print('match------->' + patron)
            else: 
                print('NO match------->' + patron)

#       cerramos la conexion
        ftp.close()
```

El problema es que al recorrer fichero con el bucle for no lista ninguna coincidencia, con el endswith tampoco me encuentra nada, ¿Algún error?

listado del directorio
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, para preguntas de este tipo es **fundamental** mostrar el contenido del fichero (o lo esencial como su estructura) y el resultado que esperas y el resultado que estás consiguiendo.

Comment: puedes que el .qvw es una extension  y solo preguntarias por los archivos que finalicen en ".qvw"

Comment: Bienvendio creo que los que buscas es esto: [yahoo respuestas](https://es.answers.yahoo.com/) y esto es stackoverflow una comunidad de desarrolladores informáticos, en la cual otros desarrolladores pueden encontrar soluciones a problemas de programación en diferentes lenguajes.

Comment: Si lo único que quieres es aquellos que tengan esa extensión entonces puedes `fichero.endswith(patron)`.

Comment: vale, he probado tu aporte de fichero.endswith(patron) pero no me encuentra ninguna coincidencia.

Comment: Debes especificar el patron que estás usando y el formato de la variable `fichero` o `listadoFich`.

Comment: listadoFich es un listado de un directorio, justo lo que ves en la foto que subi.......patron='.qvw'